# Dishonored PC god mode?

Tags: dishonored, cheats

Is there a cheat for the singleplayer mode? All that I find on the net are links to 'trainers', lists of Steam achievements, generic hints and Youtube walkthroughs.

Comment: Why..... It's not like this game is hard...

Comment: A trainer should do what you want.

Comment: @Warface Bethesda is the publisher of [Dishonored](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Dishonored_(video_game)), but Arkane Studios is the developer. Dishonored uses the Unreal Engine 3, while the Elder Scrolls series doesn't.

Comment: Unfortunately the "trainer" stuff on Cheat Happens is the only thing I can find, sorry.

Comment: Hmm.. what's wrong with a trainer?

Comment: I did something that made me effectively invincible in the game. I called it "knife everyone in the face before they get a chance to shoot you"

Comment: @deutschZuid True. But if you want to just spree and have fun on a second play through, logistical hassles like dying or resource management get in the way.

Answer (score 2):

If not interested in trainers, no, there are not any ways to cheat in Dishonored. 
The debug console was removed prior to release.